# Unable to get json data from curl graph api using c#

Tags: c#, curl, libcurl

I'm executing curl graph api using c#.

I took my curl query used this website and convert it into c#.
https://curl.olsh.me/

Api is able to give 200 ok status code and but output is below-

```
{
  "extensions" : {
    "requestId" : "123"
  },
  "data" : null,
  "errors" : [ {
    "message" : "Unable to process JSON",
    "extensions" : {
      "errorType" : "developer_error",
      "errorClass" : "VALIDATION"
    }
  } ]
}
result string conv: StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Connection: keep-alive
  Braintree-Version: 2016-10-07
  Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
  Vary: Braintree-Version
  X-Cache: Miss from cloudfront
  X-Amz-Cf-Pop: MIA3-C2
  X-Amz-Cf-Id: 111
  Date: Tue, 10 Sep 2019 16:13:54 GMT
  Via: 1.1 demo.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
  Content-Length: 286
  Content-Type: application/json
}
```

C# code -

```
    HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
    {                
        UseProxy = false,
    };

    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler))
    {
        using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), "https://demo/graphql"))
        {
            // Prod token
            request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", "Basic abc");     
            request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Braintree-Version", "2019-01-01");
            request.Content = new StringContent("{\"query\": \"{ report { transactionLevelFees(date: \"2019-08-28\"){ url } } }\" }", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
            var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);

            // Get the response content.
            HttpContent responseContent = response.Content;
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
            // Get the stream of the content.
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(await responseContent.ReadAsStreamAsync()))
            {
                // Write the output.
                Console.WriteLine((await reader.ReadToEndAsync()));
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"result string conv: {response }");
        }
    }
```

> I expect in output i should get something in data json

Comment: are you sure your query is correct? can you set up something online for us to test?

Comment: yes query is correct because when i execute same into my curl command it works

Comment: Maybe it's a `TryAddWithoutValidation` error. It acctepts `TryAddWithoutValidation(String, IEnumerable<String>)` but you have `TryAddWithoutValidation(String, String)`. It's hard to tell with no code example to go off of.

Comment: i took my curl query used `https://curl.olsh.me/` and used above c# code.
can you do same with any sample curl? please guide me

Comment: Sure, I'll try my best but I might not be able to get to it today.

Comment: thanks a lot in advance ... later pls post here that will be helpful to me... i'm pretty new to curl

Comment: What is that post URL `https://demo/graphql` is that s your endpoint?